# Content navigation breaks after first level

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Currently I have setup a small test application and ran into some trouble lately. After some tries I still don't know where my mistake is.

Here is my pen: `http://codepen.io/ins0/pen/wtELa`

The problem is that after clicking the side navigation the content normally shows up, navigation updates. When I click on a link inside the content - the url state changes (eg. `from #/settings` to `#/settings/about`, xhr gets fired and received but the content doesn't get replaced.

I tried listening to all state events but no error is thrown.

Comment: Please post your MCV code here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the mistake by myself. In order to get the navigation correct you need to set a a viewtarget in your router configuration for childen pages that point to your parent view. Like this:

`state('app.settings.about', {
                        url: "/about",
                        views: {
                            'content@app' :{
                                templateUrl: "about.html"
                            }
                        }
                    });`

see`'content@app'`. this tells the framework to render the about view in the content field defined in route `app`. I updated the codepen to a working example.